# How to manage common files accross a large number of projects?

Tags: build, configuration, continuous-integration, development-environment, configuration-files

By common files, I dont mean the code or libraries used in the application itself but I mean the "meta" files like CI/CD configurations, make files etc. These files can be common to a lot of projects especially if you use the same (or similar) stack for multiple projects.

However these files also need to be in each project and generally ends up being copied over. And so comes the issue when you need to modify something and you end up having to change each and every file. This becomes a big mess very fast especially if you have a lot of projects. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what is your programming env ?

Comment: I am into golang these days, but the question not specifically about golang

Answer (score 0):

If yo create a ton of projects, all with the same configuration/travis files, I would recommend something like yeoman:

http://yeoman.io/

This way you can create project "skeletons" that can be replicated all across your projects.

If later on you update a "skeleton", you copies can also be updated by running a simple command.